# Powershell, Pester and Enable-ADAccount

Tags: powershell, mocking, pester

In my module PSCHSGActiveDirectory, I have a function Set-CHSGActiveUserActiveOn which call 2 functions from ActiveDirectory module : Get-ADUser and Enable-ADAccount.

```
Function Set-CHSGActiveUserActiveOn() {
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $True,
            ValueFromPipeline = $True
        )]
        [String]$samAccountName
    )
    ...
    $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $SamAccountName
    ...
    Enable-ADAccount -Identity $user
    ...
}
```

Here, my pester test file :

```
BeforeAll {
    Import-Module PSCHSGActiveDirectory -Force
}

Describe 'Set-CHSGActiveUserActiveOn' {
    Context 'Without Reset Password' {
        BeforeAll {
            #Mock Get-ADUser -ModuleName PSCHSGActiveDirectory { }
            #Mock Enable-ADAccount -ModuleName PSCHSGActiveDirectory { }
        }

        It 'Tests Enable User' {
            PSCHSGActiveDirectory\Set-CHSGActiveUserActiveOn -SamAccountName 'johndoe' | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
        }
    }
}
```

When i didn't mock anything, test failed on Get-ADUser.

When i mock only Get-ADUser, test failed on Enable-ADAccount with the message :

```
[-] Set-CHSGActiveUserActiveOn.Without Reset Password.Tests Enable User 42ms (40ms|2ms)
 ValidationMetadataException: L’argument est Null. Spécifiez une valeur valide pour l’argument, puis réessayez.
 ParameterBindingValidationException: Impossible de valider l'argument sur le paramètre «*Identity*». L’argument est Null. Spécifiez une valeur valide pour l’argument, puis réessayez.
```

When i mock both, test still failed on Enable-ADAccount with the same message

I try to change my function Set-CHSGActiveUserActiveOn with the use of a param Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser instead of a string (and delete the Get-ADuser of course) but the problem still here.

I use these versions :

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   1.0.1.0    ActiveDirectory                     {Add-ADCentralAccessPolicyMember, Add-ADComputerServiceAccount, Add-ADDomainControllerPasswordReplicationPolicy, Add-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicySubject...}
Binary     1.0.0.0    CimCmdlets                          {Export-BinaryMiLog, Get-CimAssociatedInstance, Get-CimClass, Get-CimInstance...}
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Content...}
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {ConvertFrom-SecureString, ConvertTo-SecureString, Get-Acl, Get-AuthenticodeSignature...}
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.WSMan.Management          {Connect-WSMan, Disable-WSManCredSSP, Disconnect-WSMan, Enable-WSManCredSSP...}
Script     5.3.1      Pester                              {Add-ShouldOperator, AfterAll, AfterEach, Assert-MockCalled...}
Script     3.4.0      Pester                              {AfterAll, AfterEach, Assert-MockCalled, Assert-VerifiableMocks...}
Script     2.0.0      PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption, Remove-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler...}
```

I suppose it is just a syntax problem to mock Enable-ADAccount but i can't find any ways.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Maybe just an issue with your example, but you use `-User` instead of `-samAccountName` when calling `Set-CHSGActiveUserActiveOn`

Comment: yes it is just for example, in fact i tried 2 things :

- Param $samAccountName to use with a Get-ADUser

- Param $user to use directly without Get-ADUser

Thanks for that, i change my example

Answer (score 0):

If the flow of the tested function expects a result from a called cmdlet, you should always return (a mocked) result from that function.

Change the Mocks to something like this:

```
Mock Get-ADUser -ModuleName PSCHSGActiveDirectory { 
   return $Identity
}
Mock Enable-ADAccount -ModuleName PSCHSGActiveDirectory { }
```

`$Identity` is the value of the `-Identity` parameter as made available within the Mock by Pester. You could also return a fixed value, eg. `"user"` or another (script) variable

Comment: Thank you for answer. When i don't use Get-ADUser in my function and i change the param $samAccountName by the param $user, problem is the same.
I mean, Enable-ADAccount is alone in my tested function. So, i don't understand why Get-ADUser doesn't need attributes but Enable-ADAccount need.